# GUI for editing Menu in Xubuntu

Tags: menu, xubuntu

I see that Xubuntu has package Gnome-menus, but I cannot find the command to run the editor it should contain. I found a small editor but it does not allow new entries and alacarte tries to install whole Gnome...

So I'm looking for a menu editor that will allow me to:

- Add new launchers,
- Edit existing ones
- Move existing ones to different categories
- Create new categories
- Won't install bazillion dependencies :)

Comment: http://xfcemenuedit.mon-asso.org/index.en.html

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting, but I guess it's not packaged for Xubuntu?

Comment: You want a .deb file i'm guessing?, nope that menu editor has to be built.

Comment: Here's another link http://xubuntu.wordpress.com/2006/07/12/manually-edit-the-xfce-menu/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## 11.04

*(and works for all versions since 11.04)*

The use of `alacarte` in the current version of xubuntu is perhaps not a good choice because of its perceived gnome dependencies - it is actually packaged wrongly, but that's a different story.

### Xubuntu / Lubuntu Menu editor

You could try the following java based menu editor which works for both Xubuntu and Lubuntu:
[image]

To install, [download and extract](http://lxmed.sourceforge.net/download.html) into your Downloads folder

Then open your terminal:

if you havent already installed java

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

followed by

```
cd ~/Downloads/lxmed
chmod +x install.sh
```

If the folder `/opt` does not exist then

```
sudo mkdir /opt
```

Finally

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

You launch the menu editor by `Start - Settings - Main Menu Editor`

Comment: This is app works great if I just run manually the .jar file, but I can't install it, seems my Xubuntu does not have an opt directory... how to bypass this?

Comment: How very weird - mine is a fresh xubuntu install and it has /opt.  Try `sudo mkdir /opt` to create the folder.

Comment: running xUbunto dekstop (Xfce4) on top of Ubuntu server 11.04. This utility did not accomplish anything. The problem I have is that the Main Menu does not expose the System > Preferences or System Administration menu items and their sub-menus

Answer (score 4):

## 11.10 & 12.04

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte --no-install-recommends
```

This will let you use an editor to change the menus.

Xfce 4.8 is used in Xubuntu 11.10 and Xubuntu 12.04.

Using this command to install will not bring in all the gnome dependencies that are not needed for Xfce.

Comment: Just tried this in Xubuntu 11.10. Alacarte installs & appears in 'Settings' as 'Main Menu' and lets you select and deselect items, but creating new items doesn't work. EDIT: It appears alacarte has an unrecognised dependency: gnome-panel. See [this launchpad bug report] (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alacarte/+bug/826049 ). Installing gnome-panel's sylphlike 150mb did indeed restore this rather useful functionality.