# How can I install a package without installing its dependencies?

Tags: apt, synaptic

I'm trying to install [Alacarte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alacarte) and the dependencies are huge, basically all of GNOME. I know that they are unnecessary. Is there an option in [Synaptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_%28software%29) or an [apt-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) flag for this?

Comment: big difference between recommends and dependencies

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two kinds of dependencies for [alacarte](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/alacarte): “depends” and “recommends”.

Alacarte depends on Python and various Python libraries (which in turn pull in some libraries); the “depends” level says that alacarte won't work without these. APT-based tools won't let you install alacarte without those dependencies. You can ignore all dependencies with `dpkg --force-depends`, however this will confuse APT when alacarte is involved in a dependency calculation later (for example when a newer version of the package appears), hence doing this is not recommended. Furthermore it's unlikely that you'll get any use of the package without these dependencies.

Alacarte depends on [gnome-panel](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/gnome-panel) (which in turns depends on many other parts of Gnome) at the “recommends” level. This indicates that alacarte is rarely useful without gnome-panel, but can be in some circumstances. Here, alacarte is indeed useful without gnome-panel if you have a different Freedesktop-compliant menu application.

By default, `apt-get install` installs all dependencies at the “depends” or “recommends” level. Pass the `--no-install-recommends` option to tell it not to install “recommends”-level dependencies. You can make this the default setting by adding `APT::Install-Recommends "false";` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/zzz_mpmcfarlane`.

With `aptitude` on the command line, pass `-R` or `--without-recommends` to avoid installing “recommends”-level dependencies. In the Aptitude full-screen UI, marking alacarte for installation also selects gnome-panel, but you can unmark it before proceeding with the installation. The APT preference also influences aptitude.

In Synaptic, marking alacarte for installation also selects gnome-panel. However you can go and unmark gnome-panel before applying the changes. There is a preference (in the “General” tab) to “Consider recommended packages as dependencies”.

Comment: Thank you, very good answer, changed it from about a hundred packages to about four.

Answer (score 9):

The key option to add to `apt-get` is `--no-install-recommends`

So for alacarte -

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends alacarte
```

Given that alacarte is default in standard Ubuntu, can I ask what variant of Ubuntu are you installing alacarte for?

If you are using Xubuntu or Lubuntu - can I recommend an alternative menu editor from the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54303/gui-for-editing-menu-in-xubuntu).  I've found that alacarte doesnt work with both Lubuntu and Xubuntu.

Answer (score 8):

You can download the .deb package (`apt-get download foo`) and install it via `dpkg` using the `--force-depends` option.

Comment: how to locate the .deb file if all I have is the name of the package?

Comment: replying to myself: `apt-get download foo`