# How do I remove OpenJDK without losing JDownloader?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, jdownloader

I recently installed Sun's Java because of performance issues running Minecraft.

When I try to remove the OpenJDK packages by

`sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`

however, the JDownloader package is being removed as well.
If I try to remove all OpenJDK-7 packages one by one, OpenJDK-6 is being installed instead.

IMHO there should be a way to satisfy JDownloader's dependencies for a Java runtime environment with Sun's version.

Is there any way to keep JDownloader while completely removing the opensource Java versions?

EDIT: As explained by user tumbleweed, this issue was caused by a temporary bug which soon afterwards has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer here is that that package was buggy, it depended on specific JDKs rather than the generic `javaX-runtime` virtual packages.

I pointed this out to the maintainer of the PPA, and he's uploaded a new version that depends on `default-jre | java6-runtime | java7-runtime`. This should be satisfied by the Sun JDK.

Comment: Good work! I've tried to install the ppa version and it's functioning again like it should. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could let the system remove it and then install it again with the option `--no-install-recommends`.

That will ignore the necessary dependencies listed on the package and install only the package it self.

More information on that subject here:

- [How can I install a package without installing its dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55244/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-its-dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried that, but since openjdk is marked as a dependency, not a recommendation, for JDownloader, this won't work. Upon reinstallation of JDownloader (from this ppa:jd-team/jdownloader), openjdk is being reinstalled as well.

Comment: Then download the package and install it with `dpkg --force-depends` as suggested on the linked answer.

Comment: I just tried that by myself and it worked. Again, thank you very much!