# Using apt install --ignore-depends causes apt to stop working and insist on running --fix-broken install

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I was following an article like this one:

[How can I install a package without installing its dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55244/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-its-dependencies)

```
sudo dpkg --install --ignore-depends=libssl1.1 easytether_0.8.9_amd64.deb
```

That works great, `libssl1.1` isn't installed (I've manually sym linked to the library for this legacy app).

But now all future installs fail and depend I run `--fix-broken install`:

```
$ sudo apt install iw
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 easytether : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I can't fix it because `libssl1.1` isn't supported and isn't a package I can install, hence my need to sym link to the specific `.so` file that legacy app needs. If I run `apt --fix-broken install` it will simply uninstall the `.deb` file from above.

But how can I force `apt` to forever ignore the fact that it's missing that dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently support for `libssl1.1` got deprecated [here the package page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish-updates/libssl1.1) because of security reasons.

- First, ask the devs of easytether to switch to `libssl3`.
- But in the meantime [someone made a back port here](https://launchpad.net/%7Enrbrtx/+archive/ubuntu/libssl1) install the PPA and you should be set.
- And also, in the future, for package problems use [http://packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com)

Comment: Already tried bullet one, no response. But point two looks like a great solution.

Comment: tho not the best and defently not permiate

Comment: No luck on the backport. Althought that page says it's openssl 1.1, the package name is not `libssl1.1`, it's `libssl1`, so `apt` is still complaining about the package not being available.

Comment: you can downlaod the deb off of the package page https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libssl1.1 go to amd64 and then click a mirror