# Lubuntu to provide menu access to Skype for alternate users

Tags: lubuntu, skype

I have installed Skype on Lubuntu 14.04 using the `owner` account. The `owner` can invoke it through the menu selections `Internet > Skype`.

The `kids` account can run Skype by selecting `Run` and typing `Skype`. It would be better for the `kids` account to have menu access to Skype. How can this be done?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: The `owner` installed it via `sudo apt-get update` `apt-get install skype` `apt-get install -f`, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Since `kids` are not sudoers, they cannot install Skype again but since it's already installed, that would seem sub-optimal.

Comment: Elevating `kids` to administrators, I tried to have them install Skype, but apt-get indicated that Skype was already installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use [MenuLibre](https://launchpad.net/menulibre) any time I need to edit the menu. It works for Gnome, LXDE, XFCE, or Unity.

Comment: Skype suddenly appeared in the `kids` Internet menu after the `owner` installed `MenuLibre`.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for editing the menu [are on the Lubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/EditingTheMenu). I thought a main-menu-editor GUI was coming, but I can't spot that information just now.

You can also try the GUI solutions previously noted: [for Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/196614/38585) and for [X/Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/54303/38585).